# Non-Deprecated Data Binding for SWT/JFace

Tags: java, data-binding, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have been toying around with Eclipse plug-in development recently and when I tried to bind an SWT `Text` to a `String` in my data model using the Eclipse *Bindings* tab, the code it generated was relying on deprecated classes like `WidgetProperties`and `PojoProperties`.

Are there any newer classes I missed out on? Is there an *easy* way to do the data binding without having to suppress warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `WidgetProperties` use the class in the `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.typed` package rather than the deprecated classes in `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt`.

For `PojoProperties` and `BeanProperties` the replacement is in `org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans.typed` rather than `org.eclipse.core.databinding.beans`

`ViewerProperties` in `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewer` has also been replaced with a class in `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.viewers.typed`

The classes in the `xxx.typed` package have been modified to use generics.

Comment: Interesting! Well, that worked. I had discovered in the meantime that the Vogella JFace Data Binding tutorial recommends suppressing the warning, which is unsatisfying ofc. Weirdly enough they import from swt.typed right above section 1.2.:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDataBinding/article.html

Are these new packages largely undocumented as of yet? Because search engines don't display much meaningful results when looking for `org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.typed`. In fact, this thread here is the current top result using duckduckgo.

Comment: Documentation on all this is pretty sparse, I just saw these changes when they appeared a few releases ago in the "what's new" in the release notes.