# Cant create new FXML File in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml

When Im trying create a new FXML File in  Eclipse (File -> New -> Other -> JavaFX - new FXML Document -> Next) nothing happens. It doesnt create a File. Same Problem when I try to create FXGraph or JavaFX HTML Template whatever those are. After I try to create I get this Error Message :

```
eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.5
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.ui
Error
Sun Dec 11 06:12:31 CET 2022
Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties
    at org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.wizards.AbstractJDTElementPage.createControl(AbstractJDTElementPage.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1182)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1235)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:918)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties cannot be found by org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui_3.8.0.202204150904
    ... 67 more
```

I tried to reinstall JavaFX and SceneBuilder but it changed nothing.
Reinstalling Eclipse Software also wasnt helping.

Comment: [`org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties` was deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362249/non-deprecated-data-binding-for-swt-jface) and likely removed, which is probably why it can't be found. Ensure that you are using the most recent stable versions of all software. If so, contact the developers of the wizard you using, which is broken, and file an issue or bug for them to fix. Perhaps reverting to an earlier version may work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like e(fx)clipse hasn't been updated for 2022-12, which [removed](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.ui/pull/323) some DataBinding APIs.

You can open an issue at https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-eclipse/issues, but if you can work up a pull request to fix it, that'll probably move things along far more quickly.

Answer (score 8):

This issue has been fixed with e(fx)clipse 3.10.0 (see [commit 9a01848](https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-eclipse/commit/9a01848e48d3ad6f8e8faa888911988bab6c94c2)). For some reason, the version available on the Eclipse Marketplace is out of date by at least two versions already, as of writing. I'd also rather not downgrade my current version of Eclipse just to make this work.

You can get the latest version by using the nightly software site instead:

- Go to **Help > Install New Software**
- Click the **Add...** button beside **Manage...**.
- A dialog titled **Add Repository** will appear, asking for a name and location.

  - For the name field, you can insert something like `e(fx)clipse nightly`.
  - For the location field, insert `https://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/updates-nightly/site/`
  - Click **Add**.
- Once done, the following list should appear:
  [image: Install New Software]
- Check all the items and click **Next**.
- The next window will show you a list of items to be installed, just click **Finish** and wait for it to complete the installation.

Comment: I used to fix my problem. I am using Eclipse 2023-03 and it works well. Thank you

Comment: It works for me with Eclipse 2023-06. Thanks!

Comment: works in 2023-09

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround to this problem.

1. Create a new JavaFX Project
   [Eclipse Project Creation Wizard Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbl1R.png)
2. Rename the FXMLDocument to something unique
   [JavaFX Project Navigator Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW6Ln.png)
3. Right-click and copy the .FXML file from the bogus project you just created
4. Right-click in your real project and paste the .FXML file into the actual project
   [New .FXML file is in the original JavaFX Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lcrz.png)
5. Delete the bogus JavaFX Project to clean up
6. Nod sagely and pat yourself on the back

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it was because I was using eclipse 12-2022. Just downgrade it to eclispe 09-2022.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found to get SceneBuilder to work was:

- create a generic file but name it with a .fxml
- go to Window->Preferences->JavaFX and in the SceneBuilder executable box paste the path to the scenebuilder executable file on your computer
- right click on the newly created .fxml file->open with scenebuilder

this was in version 2022-12

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears because the newest version of Eclipse doesn't comes with "JFace Data Binder Library" which is necessary for the FXML files, which is also not available on the Eclipse Marketplace.

So I suggest you to download the 2021-09.(4.21) version which you can find over here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Download this version of Eclipse and that's all you will be able to create your FXML file. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Try Creating the FXML file manually by **New > File**  Enter the file name with the extension .fxml

After that set up scene builder path by **Window > Preferences > JavaFX** Browse and select SceneBuilder.exe to Scenebuilder executable **Apply and close**

Finally Right click the .fxml file that we have created manually and Click **open with SceneBuilder**