# An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties

Tags: eclipse

I tried creating a new FXML file in my Javafx project but this error pops up. I use eclipse IDE 2022-12, But it works fine on a different PC with Eclipse IDE 2022-06.

Is it an issue with the update and are there any patches that can help resolve this issue?
Below is the error log;

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2022-12-28 18:52:06.915
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties
at org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui.wizards.AbstractJDTElementPage.createControl(AbstractJDTElementPage.java:109)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:178)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:744)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1182)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1223)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1223)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:73)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage.lambda$0(NewWizardNewPage.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:780)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:777)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1542)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:272)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:329)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:263)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:317)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:251)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:485)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:389)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4256)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4054)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3642)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:643)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:550)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:171)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1440)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jface.databinding.swt.WidgetProperties cannot be found by org.eclipse.fx.ide.ui_3.8.0.202204150904
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 68 more

Comment: So what does the error log say? A lot more information is necessary to answer this question. Anything else would be coffee guessing.

Comment: This is what it says "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties"

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties

Comment: A plug-in you are using needs to be updated for Eclipse 2022-12 which no longer has that class. Show us the full stack trace from the log and we may be able to tell you which plug-in ([edit] your question to add the details).

Comment: Okay, I've added the error log to the body of the question

Comment: Seems to be an update issue, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74758879/20881645 provides more insight. Thanks for your help