# Eclipse jee 2022-12 and e(fx)clipse 3.8.0

Tags: java, eclipse, efxclipse

I installed Eclipse jee 2022-12 and then installed from the Marketplace e(fx)clipse 3.8.0. I am unable to create a JavaFX Main class. I use the package explorer and then New -> Other -> JavaFX -> Classes -> JavaFX Main class. When I press the Next button, nothing happens - the window where I could enter the name of the class is not displayed. I am using Windows 10 and I tried this on two different systems - with the same result.
The same process works perfectly fine when using Eclipse jee 2022-09
Thanks
Walter Taus

Comment: Can you create a normal main class extending `Application` and calling `Application.launch` in the main? Is there anything shown in the Error log view (`Window`>`Show View`>`Error Log`)?

Comment: Sounds like the same cause as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758570/cant-create-new-fxml-file-in-eclipse/74758879, but there's no way to tell without the error log.

Comment: @nitind The error log shows: Unhandled event loop exception (org.eclipse.ui)

Comment: @dan1st: creating  a normal main class and turning it into extends Application does work without a problem

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace from the error log? Until this problem is resolved, just work around it by creating a normal main class inheriting from `Application`.

Comment: @nitind I just tried with Eclipse 2023-03 M2. The problem is still there

Comment: @dan1st eclipse.buildId=4.26.0.20221201-1200
java.version=17.0.6
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.ui
Error
Sun Feb 12 11:47:39 CET 2023
Unhandled event loop exception

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jface/databinding/swt/WidgetProperties

Comment: That class [has been removed in 2022](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_actions.htm&cp%3D2_0_13_8). Try updating e(fx)clipse if it is fixed on their side.