# javaFX not launching window - windows/eclipse/scene builder

Tags: windows, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am running the latest version of eclipse and using the most recent javaFX download from the website. I am on windows 11. I have set up javaFX add on inside eclipse, and added the user library with the SDK jar files, edited the run configuration with the VM argument. When I created the project I selected the language as FXML and set the name to 'Main' and 'MainController'. I'm not getting any errors in eclipse, but when I go to run it nothing happens. No error messages are displayed or anything. All the tutorials I found will run and launch an empty window for the program based off the code that initially populates in the javaFX project. I don't understand what I'm missing. If it helps this is what the code that populates looks like:
`package application;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root =    BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
             scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
      }
```

}`

I tried re-installing eclipse in case I set it up wrong when I installed javaFX. I used this person's instructions for an updated javaFX resources to create multiple FXML files https://stackoverflow.com/a/76298615/22212735 I have tried looking at different tutorials. I still can't get it to launch.

Comment: Start here -> https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/